# JavaFX project can't launch on Visual Studio Code (no build tools)

Tags: java, linux, visual-studio-code, javafx

I have a very basic JavaFX project that is supposed to open a new window (a scene). I'm trying to Launch it on VSCode.

```java
package project;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
 
public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Button btn = new Button();
        btn.setText("Say 'Hello World'");
        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.getChildren().add(btn);
  
  Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);
  
  primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
 
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

I think I've done  everything I'm supposed to:

- I downloaded javafx-sdk (version 19.0.2.1) and added all the `lib` files to my project's `lib`.
- I have java (version openjdk 19.0.2 )
- In the file /.vscode/launch.json I added the compile arguments:

```json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "java",
            "name": "Launch App",
            "request": "launch",
            "mainClass": "project.Main",
            "vmArgs": "--module-path /home/user/openjfx-19.0.2.1_linux-x64_bin-sdk/javafx-sdk-19.0.2.1/lib --add-modules javafx.controls, javafx.fxml",
        }
    ]
}
```

I tried launching it via the "Run" menu with or without debugging and it doesn't do anything. I don't get any errors or console output.

Comment: I downloaded java via apt-get and added the correct path to JAVA_HOME environmental variable.

Comment: try removing the space between "`javafx.controls, javafx.fxml`" (the space after the comma). spaces are typically trated as field separators in shells. I'm guessing that's the issue here. [The one in the tutorial linked above](https://github.com/openjfx/samples/blob/master/IDE/VSCode/Non-Modular/Java/hellofx/.vscode/launch.json) has no space there

Comment: Your main class is wrong, you have `"mainClass": "project.Main"`, but the class is named `project.App`.

Answer (score 1):

Your main class is `project.App`, but in your launch config, you specified `"mainClass": "project.Main",`. Change your launch config to `"mainClass": "project.App"`.

If fixing that alone isn't enough, I'd try also removing the space between `"javafx.controls, javafx.fxml"` (the space after the comma). spaces are typically treated as field separators in shells. The one in [the tutorial I'm guessing you're following](https://github.com/openjfx/samples/blob/master/IDE/VSCode/Non-Modular/Java/hellofx/.vscode/launch.json) has no space there.

Comment: I actually had fixed the name, but forgot to mention it. I also removed the space you suggested but it still doesn't work.